# Error: Simultaneous accesses to 0x100e0b108, but modification requires exclusive access

Tags: swift, xcode, runtime-error, core-bluetooth

I am working on a Bluetooth chat app using CoreBluetooth.

```
func updateAdvertisingData() {
    
    if (peripheralManager.isAdvertising) {
        peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
    }
    
    let userData = UserData()
    let advertisementData = String(format: "%@", userData.name)          peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:[WR_UUID], CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: advertisementData])
}

func addOrUpdatePeripheralList(device: Device, list: inout Array<Device>) {

    if !list.contains(where: { $0.peripheral.identifier == device.peripheral.identifier }) {
        
        list.append(device)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else if list.contains(where: { $0.peripheral.identifier == device.peripheral.identifier
        && $0.name == "unknown"}) && device.name != "unknown" {
        
        for index in 0..<list.count {
            
            if (list[index].peripheral.identifier == device.peripheral.identifier) {
                
                list[index].name = device.name
                break
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }}}
    extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                
                print(visibleDevices.count)
                return visibleDevices.count
               
            }
    
extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
        func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
            if central.state == .poweredOn {
                
                self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
        }}

        func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
            var peripheralName = cachedPeripheralNames[peripheral.identifier.description] ?? "unknown"
            
            if let advertisementName = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String {
                
                peripheralName = advertisementName
                cachedPeripheralNames[peripheral.identifier.description] = peripheralName
            }
            
            let device = Device(peripheral: peripheral, name: peripheralName)
            
            self.addOrUpdatePeripheralList(device: device, list: &visibleDevices)
            self.addOrUpdatePeripheralList(device: device, list: &cachedDevices)
         }
        func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
            peripheral.delegate = self
            peripheral.discoverServices(nil) }} 
    extension ViewController: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
        func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
            
            if (peripheral.state == .poweredOn) {
                print("peripheralManagerDidUpdateState")
                
                updateAdvertisingData()}}
```

I have added the code also now. Here I am getting ***Simultaneous accesses to 0x100e0b108, but modification requires an exclusive access*** error on the return statement. I am using swift 5, development target is iOS 12.4.

Here the device will act both as a peripheral and a central.

Comment: Are you perhaps updating the `visibleDevices` array from a core Bluetooth delegate function?  If so you should dispatch that update onto the main queue

Comment: @Paulw11
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

I have dispatched the central manager on main queue.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have updated the question with the code. Can please you help me figure out now?